# Add subView immediately after view presented

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 view A and B.
At view A

```
presentViewController(viewB, animation: true) {
  NSNotificationCenter.defautCenter.postNotificationName("addButton")
}
```

At view B:
var masterView:UIView!

```
func addButton(notification: NSNotification){
    var button:UIButton!
    button.frame = masterView.caculator // set frame for button
    self.addSubview(button)
}
```

When view B finished animation on simulator( go from Bottom). Button added after delay 0.3s.

Following some document, when animation finish, method viewDidAppear called. i tried this way. But as I saw, button added after animation finish 0.3s

How to addButton immediately when animation finish?
 Thank you!

Comment: why you are not add in xib or storyboard

Comment: @MikeAlter because I use masterView size is dynamic in each viewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. Because in `viewDidAppear`, this method was called when all Layout is loaded.
So we need implement add my button in `LayoutSubview` Method.